# Expected type 'Sized', got 'TextField' instead

Tags: django, django-models, pycharm

I am working on a small project with Django and i have to validate the size for a text field and then return some data based on the condition. I am using the len() method to check the TextField() size and then return some data. The code is working, but I have an error from the IDE (Pycharm) that says: "Expected type 'Sized', got 'TextField' instead". I spent some time looking in some resources online but i can't find anything related to my issue.

Have you deal with this before?

Here's the code:

`

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text


 

    class Entry(models.Model):
         """Something specific learned about a topic."""
         topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         text = models.TextField()
         date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        if len(self.text) < 50:
            return f"{self.text}"
        return f"{self.text[:50]}..."
```

`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an indentation problem, or did you put indentations wrong here? your code should be:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text


 

class Entry(models.Model):
     """Something specific learned about a topic."""
     topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     text = models.TextField()
     date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        if len(self.text) < 50:
            return f"{self.text}"
        return f"{self.text[:50]}..."
```